# Parallax scrolling(using JavaScript) issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use parallax scrolling using JavaScript and Bootstrap. It is working but the footer is also moving along with the scroll-able content and I want that the footer should be fixed at the bottom.

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>

<style type="text/css">
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #image {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1
    }

    #content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        height: 750px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:  #4dbbac;
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }

</style>



<script type="text/javascript">  

       var yPos, image;
       function parallax (){
           yPos = window.pageYOffset;
           image = document.getElementById('image');
           image.style.top = yPos * 1 + 'px';
       }
       window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax);  

</script>


<img id="image"  src="../images/company_img1.jpg" height="700px" width="100%" alt="companyProfile_image" class="img-responsive"/>

<div id="content"></div>


<?php
require 'footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wrapping div around the image with the css properties like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="image" src="../images/company_img1.jpg" height="700px" width="100%" alt="companyProfile_image" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This way the image won't affect the rest of the DOM when it's moved.

Comment: Thanks @sankorati for your answer. The footer is not moving but a white layer is added in the background of the content and hence when I make the content transparent I am unable to see the image.

Comment: It's not background effect, it's simply the image moving out of view due to the overflow: hidden effect. If you move the #content inside the container it should overlap when it has the background-color: transparent.